# facebook messenger bot account linking oauth and token expiration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Facebook's [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking) for account linking does no give any information whether it uses standard OAuth with token expiration and refresh instead it just states that they developed secure protocol.

So, is it even possible to think about facebook's "account linking" as **OAuth** capable? I haven't seen any info regarding **user identification token (sender/recipient id) expiration**. My concern is that this (sender/recipient id) does not mean anything if there is no way to check its validity. **Or is there?**

thx

Comment: Account linking has nothing to do with OAuth. It is a mechanism to link a messenger user with *any* external login system you might have.

Comment: ok thanks for clarification, and how reliable is that link? under what circumstances the link will expire or could it be checked for validity?